# MVC Model with items - Appending - Looks OK but it's not there

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Pulling my hear out with this.

I have a model that has a list of items as part of it.  This is "Costs"

In it's Edit view I use a for loop to show the items via an Editor Template.

I have added a link to append a new one to it, ensuring the Ids and Names generated follow the the others..
ie
ID = Costs_N__PropertyName
Name = Costs[N].PropertyName

The link calls an action which returns that sam EditorTemplate  but with custome names & Ids as per above.  A new blank row appears as expected and I am able to edit it.
However, when I attempt to save I can see that it isn't bound to the model.

I can't belive this is giving me such grief, I'd imagine that this is common place.

I'm guessing that I am missingh something obvious but I cannot see it..

In short, it all appears to be working but the appended item does not get bound the the main models Costs list.
Please please please help....Code below.

EDit view portion

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-offset-1">
        <table id="tblCosts" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Costs[0].ValidFrom)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Costs[0].ValidTo)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Costs[0].InternalCost)</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="editorRows">

                @{
                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Costs.Count; i++)
                    {
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Costs[i]);
                    }

                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery Calling action to add new row...

```
$("#addItem").click(function () {      
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            alert(html);                
             $("#editorRows").append(html);
        }
});
```

Action to add new

```
public PartialViewResult BlankCostRow( int tmpId )
{
    var itemModel = new ECodeLevel2CostViewModel();
    itemModel.Id = tmpId;          
    return this.PartialView("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ECodeLevel2CostViewModel.cshtml", itemModel);    
}
```

And the EditorTemplate...

```
@if (Model.Id >= 0)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UniqueId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValidFrom)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValidTo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InternalCost)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
else
{      
    Layout = "";
    string prefix = "Costs";
    string idPreifx = String.Format("{0}_{1}__", prefix, -Model.Id);
    string namePreifx = String.Format("{0}[{1}].", prefix, -Model.Id);

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Hidden(@namePreifx + "UniqueId", Model.UniqueId, new { name = @namePreifx + "UniqueId" })
            @Html.Hidden(@namePreifx + "Id", Model.Id, new { name = @namePreifx + "Id" })
            @Html.TextBox(@namePreifx + "ValidFrom", Model.ValidFrom, new { name = @namePreifx + "ValidFrom" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBox(@namePreifx + "ValidTo", Model.ValidTo, new { name = @namePreifx + "ValidTo" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBox(@namePreifx + "InternalCost", Model.InternalCost, new { name = @namePreifx + "InternalCost" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Firstly you don't use `EditorFor()` inside a loop - its just `@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Costs) - the `EditorFor()` method accepts `IEnumerable<T>` and generates the correctt html for each item. Secondly your not generating the correct html for the new item (and you cannot use `new { name=someValue }` - its just ignored by the helper (thankfully).

Comment: Refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options.

Comment: I'm using TextBox so the name does seem to be set correctly.

I don't want to use editor for the whole list.  I created an editor template base on a single instance of Cost.

That said - I am obviously doing something wrong sio I appreciate your input.
I'll look at those links.

Comment: Your using `Html.Hidden(@namePreifx + "UniqueId"` ... which gives it the `name` attribute - then you attempt to override it by giving it exactly the same `name` attribute it already has (but fortunately the helper ignores it). Just remove the `new { name="..." }` and you will see there is no difference in your html.

Comment: You know what - I was passing the wrong count into my Action.
I was passing in -(Costs.Count + 1).  Made negative so the EditorTemplate knows to construct the Ids.
However, I didn't need to to add the +1 (101 - zero based lists ;))
When I set the correct value it appears to work......